# Change machine name of a client from DC?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm granting least privileges needed for an account, that he could rename the computer machine name for each client. (All Windows 7 PCs)

These clients have already joined the domain, now what kind of privileges should I grant to that account? Not the domain admins group, of course.

Also I tried to grant full control of Computers objects to that account, but when I navigated to the Computer Properties tab, on Advanced System Settings tab, I clicked the button and it still asks for password of a Domain Admin account.

What's the right way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The user needs to be a local admin on the machine whose name is being changed and have "Create Computer Object" and "Delete Computer Object" on the OU that the object is in at a minimum.

Delegating full control of computer objects is more than enough. My bet is that his account wasn't a local admin on the machine whose name was being changed.